# "Posits" vs. "suggests"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

I am new to academic writing and keep seeing the word "posits". Does "the author posits" have the same value or meaning as "the author suggests"?

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary definitions of the two words show some key differences:

> [posit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/posit?s=t) — 2. to lay down or assume as a fact or principle; postulate.
>
> [suggest](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suggest?s=t) — 1. to mention or introduce (an idea, proposition, plan, etc.) for consideration or possible action: The architect suggested that the building be restored.

The primary difference worth noting is that "positing" is a much stronger type of "suggesting". Where "suggesting" merely offers a particular viewpoint for consideration, "positing" is making an assertive claim that the viewpoint is absolutely correct.